# Why doesnt this javascript inheritance work?

Tags: javascript

Im trying to get my head around javascript inheritance and this code doesnt work cant see why:

```
function Animal(){

  this.hasfur = true;

}

function Cat(){

  this.sound = "Meow";

}

$(document).ready(function(){

   Cat.protptype = new Animal();

  var myCat = new Cat();

  console.log(myCat.hasfur);


}
```

The console comes out with undefined. But I thought that when I access myCat.hasfur it should look at the prototype of cat which is vehicle and then look at that property...?

Comment: This may be obvious but isnt it `Cat.prototype` not `Cat.protptype`?

Comment: sorry yeah just saw that no runtime error so didnt spot it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read that again:

```
Cat.protptype
```

I'm pretty sure you meant:

```
Cat.prototype
```

Comment: sorry guys tried to close question yeah it was a type didnt come up because its not an error just a semantic error sorry!

Answer (score 0):

It is just a typo at

```
Cat.protptype = new Animal();
```

write

```
Cat.prototype = new Animal();
```

instead.